# Swift - Core Data Attribute EXC Bad Access

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I have a `Swift` app that I'm trying to use `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate four separate `tableviews`, which are in containers inside a main `VC`, using inheritance from a parent custom `tableview` controller class. I have a parent class with this method defined that all of my subclasses are inheriting:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    var task = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Task
    if task.isKindOfClass(Task) == true {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = task.name//EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1
    }

    return cell
}
```

I commented the line where it is giving me the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` compile error.
I know that the `Task` class object that inherits from `NSManagedObject` is successfully storing in that variable but it seems that whenever I try to access the name property (even `println` will cause the error), or any property on the object I get this compile error.

My hunch is that it has to do with four different `tableviews` trying to all access at once. I'm new to `Core Data` and not really sure.

**EDIT**

More code that might help with the problem:

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return fetchedResultsController
}

func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Task")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "priority", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultsController()
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    fetchedResultsController.performFetch(nil)

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
```

Screenshot of the entity inspector:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htyne.png

Comment: I suspect you may not have set the correct class for the entity in the model editor.  Check the class in the Data Model Inspector on the right.

Comment: I've tried setting the class name to `NameOfMyModule.Task` and doing that the downcast to `Task` from `NSManagedObject` fails. Leaving it just `Task`, I'm able to get my `if task.isKindOfClass(Task) == true {...}` to execute so I know it is downcasting properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it working!** A few things: my `name` property was `nil` because I didn't set a default value in the model inspector and needed a default value for good measure,  but more importantly: my `managedObjectContext` wasn't unwrapped with `!` in its declaration and so I didn't unwrap it on every reference to it and so sometimes I was getting the optional(`managedObjectContext?`) when I needed the unwrapped value. It was `let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext`
 but what it needed was `let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!`. Optional problems and not being aware enough of when to unwrap were my downfall. I also deleted my initial `app.sqlite` because I ran into an issue there after I changed the model assigning the default value to `name`.